# Lattice basis reduction over rings of number fields

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, computer-science, lattices, euclidean-lattices

Can one use lattice basis reduction algorithms, such as LLL over (low-rank) module lattices over rings of number fields of degree greater than 1? Is there any work on lattice reductions over Euclidean rings (for example, using BKZ, lattice enumeraiton, etc)?

Comment: There is a lot of research on ideal lattices in cryptography, see

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_lattice_cryptography

and 

https://eprint.iacr.org/

Comment: @MartinSeysen I have, I just haven’t found something for this specific instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this was studied in the following work: https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1035

Comment: Note the work [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/886) is relevant as well. In both cases, while the algorithms are often called "LLL", they do require (approximate) SVP oracles for lattices in the underlying number field. This is perhaps closer to a BKZ-type algorithm when the number field degree is large.